# How to remove a lot of elements from a multithread queue without using a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Let's say I have a multithread queue `myQueue` with 300 elements. Can I remove the 100 oldest with out having to iteratively call `myQueue.get()` 100 times in a for loop?

**note**

Trying to avoid using a for loop might seem like a weird goal but I am looking for ways to improve performance and increase simplicity of code. That's why I would like to be able to process the queue (remove the elements) in non iterative manner.

Comment: can you post your code whatever you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out something like that works and it also seems that it doesn't violate any thread safety rules.

Example

```
import Queue

myQueue = Queue.Queue()
for i in range(1,100):
    myQueue.put(i)
amount = [i for i in range(1,10)]
map(myQueue.get, amount)  # that will result in removing the 10 oldest elements
```

That is equivalent to using a for loop but the loop code is implemented in C and can result to better performance.

another way would be to use the parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function. This would divide the chunks that have to be processed in the loop in different processes

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(myQueue.get, range(1, 10))
```

Comment: This is basically doing what you said you didn't want to do... calling `get()` `amount` times.

Comment: What's the practical difference? Is this a homework problem where you're not allowed to use a loop?

Comment: So you suggest that the only advantage of using map instead of a for loop is the syntactic convenience?

Comment: Looping would be the same two lines, and it would be more readable. Under the hood, I'm pretty sure `map` is doing the same thing... it just abstracts it away.

Comment: No, actually map is faster than a for loop, it's not just an abstraction. The difference is that map implements the for loop in C for less overhead. Have a look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Comment: Ok, well, I could give it a +1 if you edit the question to mention that you're looking for a performance gain over looping, and if you quantify in the answer the gain you get from the map.

Comment: I updated the question and the answer a little bit. Thanks for the feedback.